# Whatsapp web push-notification only working when tab is opened (Chrome)

Tags: google-chrome, whatsapp

Whatsapp web push-notification only working when tab is opened (Chrome)
Unlike YouTube and Instagram whatsapp web push notification are not working when tab is closed in Windows 11.